# Conflict between multiple bibliographies in a document

Tags: natbib

I have a PhD manuscript in which I have to add a main bibliography after the conclusion section and a bibliography in each chapter. I use the natbib package. Each blibliography is saved in a separate .bib file. The main document has following structure:

```
 \documentclass[PhD,bibsection,english,french]{ulthese}
 \usepackage{chapterbib}`
    ...
    \include{introduction}                          
    \include{chap1-articles}    
    \include{chap2-articles}   
    \include{chap3-articles}   
    \include{discussion}            
    \include{conclusion}                          
    \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter*{\bibname}} 
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
    \bibliographystyle{alpha}                  
    \bibliography{bibliography}   
    \appendix
    ...
        \end{document}
```

The bibliography of the chapters is well inserted. To add a bibliography in each chapter I use :

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}    
\bibliography{referenceChap1}
```

But the main bibliography does not work in the text
[image]

When I deactivate the chapters with :

```
\include{introduction}                          
%\include{chap1-articles}    
%\include{chap2-articles}   
%\include{chap3-articles}  
\include{discussion}            
\include{conclusion}                          
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter*{\bibname}} 
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{alpha}                  
\bibliography{bibliography}   
\appendix
```

The bibliography is displayed correctly
[image]

I can't solve this conflict between the blibliographies

Comment: you need a package like chapterbib if you want to handle multiple bibliographies. Or switch from natbib to biblatex, it can handle that out-of-the-box.

Comment: I use the chapterbib package. I tried to switch to biblatex but it doesn't seem to work either